# gitversion: First tag found is skipped

Tags: gitversion

We have following branch setup:

- master and release/1.0 branches.
- master, tagged with 1.0 and producing 1.0.1, 1.0.2 versions.
- release/1.0 branch created from master, and master then tagged with 2.0.

The expectation is that both branches produce "stable" versions so there're no prerelease tags.

When running GitVersion on these branches, the release branch produces version 1.0.3 and master branch produces version 2.0.1. So far so good, this is what we expected.

Now one of our colleagues created a new feature branch from the release branch, which they then merge master into afterwards. The feature branch was then merged back into the release branch with a pull request. After the completing the pull request, GitVersion now gives 2.0.X on the release branch, instead of 1.0.X.

To try and fix the issue, we tagged the release branch with 1.0.4. However, with every new commit into release branch, the problem comes back. This forces use to manually tag every commit into release branch to give us our desired version number.

We're using GitVersion 4.0.0-beta0014 in mainline mode.

The config looks like:

```
mode: mainline
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
continuous-delivery-fallback-tag: ''
commit-message-incrementing: Disabled
branches:
  master:
    tag: ''
  feature:
    regex: features?[/-]
    tag: unstable.{BranchName}
  release:
    tag: ''
    is-mainline: true
  bugfix:
    regex: bugfix[/-]
    tag: unstable.{BranchName}
ignore:
  sha: []
```

Anybody any idea how to get out of this?

Lubos

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the "prevent merge branch increment option" - there's some documentation on it here:

https://gitversion.net/docs/configuration#prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version

basically you just set it to true in your gitversion.yml like below:

```
mode: mainline
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
continuous-delivery-fallback-tag: ''
commit-message-incrementing: Disabled
branches:
  master:
    tag: ''
  feature:
    regex: features?[/-]
    tag: unstable.{BranchName}
  release:
    tag: ''
    is-mainline: true
  bugfix:
    regex: bugfix[/-]
    tag: unstable.{BranchName}
ignore:
  sha: []
prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
```

Comment: Is the current version already 2.0.0? If so, you may have to remove some tags before it'll start working the way you intend. Also, can you add the `diagnostic` flag (should be -diag) to the command? That'll tell you where and how GitVersion is expecting the version bump to happen. If you add all that info to the question I may be able to help more

Comment: Outpu in diag mode does not tell me much... it starts with INFO [11/28/18 13:51:03:87] Fallback base version: 0.1.0 with commit count source 6b31750a5d2fec3f0747b7426b39bf98eee4b3cf (Incremented: None)   
INFO [11/28/18 13:51:03:91] Git tag '18.5.36': 18.5.36 with commit count source 2f9e4e9983fff2aed53429aadee6c1622ca08588 (Incremented: 18.5.37) which seems like it finds first tag but continue search anyway...